# How to isolate titles from these image URLs?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of image urls contained in 'images'. I am trying to isolate the title from these image urls so that I can display, on the html, the image (using the whole url) and the corresponding title.

So far I have this:

```
titles = [image[149:199].strip() for image in images]
```

This gives me the stripped title in the following format (I provide two examples to show the pattern)

**le_Art_Project.jpg/220px-**
Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-*Self-Portrait*-_Google_Art_Project.jpg

and

**cene_of_the_Prodigal_Son_-*Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-***Rembrandt-*Rembrandt_and_Saskia_in_the_Scene_of_the_Prodigal_Son*-_Google_Art_Project.jpg

The bits in **bold** (above) are the bits I would like to remove. From the start I would like to remove everything *before* **220px** and from the end: **_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg**

A newbie to python, I am struggling with syntax and furthermore as I am doing this while referring to the loop of images (list), the string manipulation is not straightforward and I am unsure of how to approach this.

The whole code for reference is below:

`webscraper.py`:

```
@app.route('/') #this is what we type into our browser to go to pages. we create these using routes
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    images=imagescrape()
    
    titles=[image[99:247].strip() for image in images]
    images_titles=zip(images,titles)
    return render_template('home.html',images=images,images_titles=images_titles)
```

What I've tried / am trying:

```
x = txt.strip("_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg")
```

Looking into strip - to get rid of the last part of the unwanted string.

I am unsure of how to combine this with getting rid of the leading string that I want to remove and also do so in the most elegant way given the structure/code I already have.

Visually, I am trying to *remove* the leading text as shown highlighted, as well as the last part of the string which is **_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg**.

Visual of HTML displayed:

[image: Visual of HTML displayed]

**UPDATE:**

Based on an answer below - which is very helpful but doesn't quite perfectly solve it, I am trying this approach (without using the unquote import if possible and pure python string manipulation)

```
def titleextract(url):
    #return unquote(url[58:url.rindex("/",58)-8].replace('_',''))
    title=url[58:]
    return title
```

The above, returns:

```
Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Self-Portrait_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/220pxRembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Self-Portrait_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg
```

**but I want:**

Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Self-Portrait

or for the second title/image in the list:

```
Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Saskia_van_Uylenburgh%2C_the_Wife_of_the_Artist_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Saskia_van_Uylenburgh%2C_the_Wife_of_the_Artist_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg
```

**I want:**

```
Rembrandt_van_Rijn_-_Saskia_van_Uylenburgh%2C_the_Wife_of_the_Artist
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide a complete example of your inputs (like, as actual formatted source code) and the expected output (again, as formatted actual source code).

Comment: This is the page I'm scraping:     html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt')
 ...and the img urls are what are going into the list 'images'. Then the titles are what I want to extract/slice from the existing URLS in the manner I have described above.

Comment: So, do all the strings always end exactly with `"_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg"`? Note, `.strip` doesn't work as you'd expect, it doesn't strip substrings, it actually just considers the set of all the characters you pass into the argument

Comment: Please provide it in the question itself as formatted text. Don't make me write code just to re-create your example.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga -sorry I don't understand. I have provided the above comment's information in the question itself. It is in the function that says exactly what is being scraped/input

Comment: You've provided a link to an external website. Provide a *wholly* contained example in the question itself. You have a bunch of third-party dependancies that are not relevant to your actual question. This is not a [mcve].

Comment: The question is quite simple. I have provided the inputs and the output required. I could delete the wikipedia page if necessary, so if anything LESS information is needed, not more? Apologies if I am just missing something or don't understand .. :(

Comment: Well, yes. Exactly. You have a bunch of irrelevant information here. Your question has nothing to do with flask or whatever framework you are showing us, it has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup, you really should just provide **example inputs** (again, as actual formatted source code, e.g `myinput = ["here's a string", "another string", "final example"]`) and the expected outputs, (again, *as actual formatted source code*)

Comment: so juanpa - thanks for your help with the question. Now, can you answer it? :)

Comment: I think the question he had was there, but far from clear. Please be nicer guys... Nicely inform him to write minimal questions and he can and probably will in the future. @MissComputing Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Much appreciated. I am a she though :)

Comment: @MissComputing Don't worry. Only a small subset of the community is like this. Unfortunately, they are usually the first ones to show up.

Answer (score 2):

**cene_of_the_Prodigal_Son_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/220px-**Rembrandt_-Rembrandt_and_Saskia_in_the_Scene_of_the_Prodigal_Son**-_Google_Art_Project.jpg**

You have this string and want to remove. Let's say I have this stored in x

```
y = x.lsplit("px-")[1] 
z = x.rsplit("_Google_Art")[0]
```

This makes a list with 2 elements: stuff before "px-" in the string, and stuff after. We're just grabbing the stuff after, since you wanted to remove the stuff before. If "px-" isn't always in the string, then we need to find something else to split on. Then we split on something towards the end, and grab the stuff before it.

Edit: Addressing comment on how to split in that loop.. I think you are referring to this: `titles=[image[149:199].strip() for image in images]`

List comps are great  but sometimes it's easier to just write it out. Haven't tested this but here's the idea:

```
titles = []
for image in images:
    title = image[149:199].strip()
    cleaned_left = title.lsplit("px-")[1]
    cleaned_title = title.rsplit("_Google_Art")[0]
    titles.append(cleaned_title)
```

Comment: Could you please use my existing code to add your answer so I can test it in my existing program. In other words, how do I integrate what you've suggested into this: titles=[image[99:247].strip() for image in images]

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't about fixing people's programs, but about helping people understand what they need to accomplish their goal. Your post is being downvoted because you're asking someone to write your code for you. Instead, you should use the least code possible to show where you are stuck so we can help you.

Comment: I understand the split or strip could be used and could do this seperately - but don't know how to incorporate it inside of the loop structure I have in the most elegant way.

Comment: thank you! I've mentioned in my answer that I've looked into split and strip. But how do I do that inside of this: titles=[image[99:247].strip() for image in images]

Comment: Also,in your answer, I don't get what the numbers are: y = x.lsplit("px-")[1]  <== the 1 and in the next example the 0

Comment: That's called indexing. Rather than try to explain it well myself I just googled an article. Here's 1 that looks decent: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-basics-of-indexing-and-slicing-python-lists-2d12c90a94cf

Comment: Thanks re updated answer. If that works when integrated into my code I'll accept - many thanks again! Will look again in the morning!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Make sure you understand how though! I recommend looking into split, strip, and indexing

Comment: Haven't got it working yet! Your answer assumes creating a completely new for loop...can it not be done more elegantly in the same line in my existing code ..

Comment: Yeah but less lines isn't always better. Line count doesn't matter, code readability does. If you think it's still readable then it's fine to do things in less lines. Anyways to do it all line just dot chain. Again, haven't tested but something like: [image[149:199].strip().lsplit("px-")[1].rsplit("_Google_Art")[0] for image in images]
Imo that's too much in one line, but it's subject to interpretation

Comment: Since the question was closed, I couldn't leave an answer. I have modified my answer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962025/jinja2-nested-for-loops-two-lists/62962268#62962268).

Comment: @DavidJayBrady - I get this error while trying your suggested fix: cleaned_left = title.lsplit("px-")[1]  >>AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lsplit'

Comment: Also, as per the question however, it needs to remove the "GoogleArtProject " at the end as the text can be variable....In some cases if the title is long, it will truncate the title, with your code. And if the title is short, it will show "GoogleArProject" at the end of the title.

Comment: @Detlef - your answer: Please do post it (now open )on this question and I'll at least upvote as it was helpful. Could I ask you please to comment with explanation all the lines you added. 1. The import 2. The function you created, specifically, this: return unquote(url[58:url.rindex("/", 58)-4]).replace('_', ' ') and 3.titles=(titleextract(src) for src in images)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re                          # regular expressions used to match strings 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup      # web scraping library
from urllib.request import urlopen # open a url connection 
from urllib.parse import unquote   # decode special url characters

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    images=imagescrape()
    # Iterate over all sources and extract the title from the URL
    titles=(titleextract(src) for src in images)
    
    # zip combines two lists into one.
    # It goes through all elements and takes one element from the first
    # and one element from the second list, combines them into a tuple 
    # and adds them to a sequence / generator.
    images_titles = zip(images, titles)
    return render_template('home.html', image_titles=images_titles)

def imagescrape():
    result_images=[]
    #html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Harry,_Duke_of_Sussex')
    html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rembrandt')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
    for image in images:
        result_images.append("https:"+image['src']+'\n') #concatenation!
    return result_images

def titleextract(url):
    # Extract the part of the string between the last two "/" characters
    # Decode special URL characters and cut off the suffix
    # Replace all "_" with spaces
    return unquote(url[58:url.rindex("/", 58)-4]).replace('_', ' ')
```

```
{% for image, title in images_titles %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="{{image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```